# Spring Data Rest PATCH and POST APIs not working

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have an issue with Spring Data Rest APIs. I created two Repository Interfaces for the two entities `Timesheet` and `TimeRecord`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "timesheet", path = "timesheet")
public interface TimesheetRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Timesheet, Long> {

    List<Timesheet> findAllByYearAndMonthAndEmployeeFirstNameAndEmployeeLastName(int year, int month, String firstName, String lastName);

    List<Timesheet> findAllByYearAndMonthAndEmployeeEmail(int year, int month, String email);

}
```

and

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "timerecord", path = "timerecord")
public interface TimeRecordRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TimeRecord, Long> {

    void deleteAllByTimesheet(Timesheet timesheet);

    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM TimeRecord tr WHERE tr.task.id = ?1")
    @Transactional
    void deleteByTaskId(Long taskId);

    @Modifying
    @Query("SELECT tr FROM TimeRecord tr WHERE tr.task.id = ?1")
    @Transactional
    List<TimeRecord> findByTaskId(Long taskId);
}
```

This is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Timesheet.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(TimeRecord.class);
    }
}
```

Here you can find the two classes I'm working with (there is a `One-To-Many` relation between them):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class TimeRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull(message = "The day is mandatory")
    @Min(value = 1)
    @Max(value = 31)
    private Integer day;
    private int workMinutes;
    private String note;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @NotNull
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private RecordTypeEnum recordType;
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Task task;
    @NotNull(message = "The timesheet is mandatory")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    private Timesheet timesheet;

    public Integer getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(Integer day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public void setDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    public int getWorkMinutes() {
        return workMinutes;
    }

    public void setWorkMinutes(int workMinutes) {
        this.workMinutes = workMinutes;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public RecordTypeEnum getRecordType() {
        return recordType;
    }

    public void setRecordType(RecordTypeEnum recordType) {
        this.recordType = recordType;
    }

    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Timesheet getTimesheet() {
        return timesheet;
    }

    public void setTimesheet(Timesheet timesheet) {
        this.timesheet = timesheet;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Timesheet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private Integer month;
    @NotNull(message = "The year is mandatory")
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private Integer year;
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private String note;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(TimesheetView.TimesheetInfo.class)
    private StatusEnum status = StatusEnum.OPEN;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "timesheet")
    private List<TimeRecord> timeRecords;
    @NotNull(message = "The employee is mandatory")
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Employee employee;

    public Integer getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(Integer month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public StatusEnum getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<TimeRecord> getTimeRecords() {
        return timeRecords;
    }

    public void setTimeRecords(List<TimeRecord> timeRecords) {
        this.timeRecords = timeRecords;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
    
}
```

When I try to save a new `TimeRecord` or update a new one with the request below, I get the error `400 - Bad Request`.

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/rest/timerecord/1
```

body of request:

```
{
    "note": "test"
}
```

However, when I try to do the same for a `Timesheet`, it works fine:

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/rest/timesheet/1
```

body of request:

```
{
    "note": "test"
}
```

I really don't understand how it is possible, and how to solve the problem... Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is in the body of the bad request response?

Comment: How are the controllers coded?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek there is no body... In Postman, I just get '1' as an answer, with status 400

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero in the controllers there is nothing related to these APIs, because they are created automatically by Spring Data Rest

Comment: Find inside the controllers where are you managing \@Patch. If there's no method with \@Patch, define it so you can debug it.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero once again: There is no custom controller code here, Spring Data REST does it all, that's the main use case for Data REST.

Comment: @lucia A `PATCH` request without request body is not really useful. What should be patched for timerecord 1 if you do not describe it in the request body?

Comment: @mle indeed, you can find the request body at the end of the post. In the comment above, I just pointed out that I get a RESPONSE without any body...

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your answer "there is no body".

Comment: Could you provide us with the domain classes of `TimeRecord` and `Timesheet`?

Comment: @mle no problem! Yes, I am going to update the post with the two classes. Thank you!

Comment: Well next step… in your unsuccessful PATCH you'd like to patch the timerecord with id `1` but I can not see any `@Id` in your `TimeRecord` class. What is the identifier for time records and for time sheets? Also, how does the URL for the successful timesheet patch request look like?

Comment: @mle you're right, sorry... the  `id` was in a  `CommonFields` class, which was extended by both  `TimeRecord` and  `Timesheet`. Now I've just updated the post with the required info.

Comment: you have really complicated VOs there...have you enabled logs, what do the logs say about the error?

Comment: @lucia I think while copying the id in your objects above, you accidently put `@Id` on the `day` field in `TimeRecord`. This does not seem right. Anyway, I'm sorry, I can not spot the error by just looking on your snippets, IMHO the solution must be covered somewhere else. Is there any chance you could provide us with a minimal sample project e.g. on Github?

Comment: i found (the first) typos, (bros): In `TimeRecord` you used `@JsonView("Timesheet...")`

Comment: https://blogs.grammatech.com/the-dangers-of-copy-and-paste :) , nice post/elaboration though! :)

Comment: nailed it!?? ;)